# Select only two checkboxes for kendotreeview

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I have treeview with checkboxes in my application had a one issue is to select only two
checkboxes by pageload remaining must be in disable. (i.e if deselect the one checkboxes remaining are in enable).

[My fiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/RHh67/47/)

```
    Code: 
           var tree= $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
            checkboxes: {
                checkChildren: true
            },

            dataSource: [{
                id: 1, text: "My Project", expanded: true, spriteCssClass: "rootfolder", items: [
                    {
                        id: 2, text: "OrderID", expanded: true, spriteCssClass: "folder", items: [
                            { id: 3, text: "a"  },
                            { id: 4, text: "b"  },
                            { id: 5, text: "c" },
                            { id: 6, text: "d" },
                            { id: 7, text: "e" }
                        ]
                    }

                ]
            }]
        }).data("kendoTreeView");

          tree.dataSource.bind("change", function (e) {
```

Comment: Which is the expected result if you click in a node with children? Not sure if that's what you want but using @ArunPJohny solution if you click on a node that has children (`My Project` or `OrderID`) children nodes are selected no matter if they are two or twenty.

Comment: here need to select only two treeview checkbox on pageload @ArunPJohny solution is given for select only two checkboxes by manual but i need by default . here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/RHh67/56/

Comment: There is something that I do not understand... how do you specify which two checkboxes you want to select on pageload? what means (for you) *by default*? Unless we understand what you want, we cannot help you.

Comment: When you observe my fiddle while page load no checkbox is checked(selected),but need to checked(select) two checkboxes by default in pageload.

Comment: Sorry for insisting **which** two do you want to get checked? any? random? first two? last two?

Comment: Actually they **are not**, that's what you want!

Comment: they are not means,is it not possible?

Comment: is it poosible selected two means first two or last two like this?

Comment: It is, **are not** means present and you want future :-)

Comment: ok thankyou for your valuable time.

Comment: Use `tree.dataItem(".k-item:nth(2)").set("checked", true);` and replace `2` by whatever you want. Check it here http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/RHh67/57/

Comment: ya thank you so much i want exactly this but while pageload remaining must be disbale if de-select(unchecked) any  one(i.e checked one) then remaining are in must be enable.

Comment: Sorry! No idea of what you want. I thought that I've answered it but seems that I didn't. There is an already accepted answer to the OP. If you are not able to write down what you want, we will not be able of helping you: sorry!

Comment: if your observe the fiddle while pageload two are select in default and remaining checkboxes are in enable.but i want to disable the remaining checkboxes and enable after uncheck on checkbox which checked by default.

Comment: Why do not move `updateChks();` to just after setting the checks? Did you try it?

Comment: hats off to you, thank you so much onabai and for your valuble time also.

Comment: hi onabai ,here in treeview only two checkboxes are checked in pageload but chart is displaying all the field values.i need to display only checkbox checked field values in chart while pageload,( after page-load it's working fine).  http://jsfiddle.net/RHh67/61/ please help this.

Comment: I cannot see any chart in your fiddle and this (afaik) is different question. Try post different post for different question making sure that most people see it.

Comment: sorry onabai i forgot to update the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/RHh67/64/

Comment: ya for that reason i posted as different questionbut  no one has given reply so i am asking you for help.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15409466/treeview-checkbox-selection-with-graph-updation-is-not-working-properly

Comment: And you didn't update the post there either and that's why I didn't answer ;-). I'll take a look into it but I will have to change slightly ArunPJohny solution: sorry!

Comment: it's ok onabai thank you for your quick response.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like

```
function updateChks(){
    var checkboxes = $('#treeview input:checkbox');
    var selected = checkboxes.filter(':checked');
    checkboxes.not(selected).prop('disabled', selected.length > 1)
}

$('#treeview').on('click', 'input:checkbox', updateChks);

updateChks();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/MM2BE/1/)

Comment: Thank you for quick reply here one more issue is by default two checkboxes are enabled in pageload. here is fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/RHh67/53/

Comment: I updated the function here id the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/MM2BE/1/.But i did'nt get any result,i want to checked 2 checkboxes by defaultly on pageload.

Comment: @sandeep which two checkboxes have to be checked

Comment: any two like "a" and "b" are checked  by default on pageload.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable time.