# Treeview checkbox selection with graph updation is not working properly

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

In my project i have chart and treeview while pageload chart update is not working properly means here in treeview only two checkboxes are checked in pageload but chart is displaying all the field values.i need to display only checkbox checked field values in chart  while pageload,( after page-load it's working fine).

here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RHh67/64/

My chart code:

```
$("#myChart").kendoChart({
    theme: $(document).data("kendoSkin") || "default",
    dataSource: {
        data: tmpData2,
        sort: {
            field: "date",
            dir: "asc"
        },
        schema: {
            model: {
                fields: {
                    date: {
                        type: "date"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: "My Date-aware Chart"
    },
    legend: {
        position: "bottom"
    },
    seriesDefaults: {
        type: "line",
        labels: {
            visible: true
        },
        missingValues: "gap"
    },
    series: series,
    valueAxis: [{
        name: "A",
        labels: {
            format: "{0}%"
        }
    },
    {
        name: "B",
        labels: {
            format: "{0}D"
        }
    }],
    categoryAxis: {
        type: "Date",
        field: "date",
        axisCrossingValue: [0, 1000]
    }

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a `redrawChart` that refreshes the Chart with the new series as:

```
function redrawChart() {
    var chart = $("#myChart").data("kendoChart");

    var checkedSeries = [];

    $("#treeview").find(":checked").each(function () {
        var nodeText = $(this).parent().parent().text();

        $.each(series, function (index, series) {
            if (series.field == nodeText) {
                checkedSeries.push(series);
            }
        });
    });

    chart.options.series = checkedSeries;
    chart.refresh();
}
```

This functions needs to be invoked:

1. On your tree change.
2. After setting the initial visible series.

In addition, move the selection of the initial series to the end of the JavaScript code. I mean, first initialize `treeview` and `chart` and only then initialize the initial values.

```
tree.dataItem(".k-item:nth(2)").set("checked", true);
tree.dataItem(".k-item:nth(3)").set("checked", true);
updateChks();
redrawChart();
```

The complete running version is in here http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/RHh67/68/

Comment: sorry where i have to ask this question i dont know for that i am asking here how to update the question in stackoverflow? is my process for asking qustion is wrong?

Comment: Those questions are asked in metaexchange. Probably you don't have reputation enough for editing the question (I already edited it for updating the link to fiddle)